# How to read Salesforce lightning components attributes from APEX

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This use case is tricky.
We need to have a way to read Salesforce lightning component attributes from the APEX code.
We don't want to pass the attributes from the Salesforce lightning javascript but wanna try to read the component attributes from the backend code.

Is it possible?

Comment: Its actually very interesting question but my guess it is not  possible to do something like that. LEX is like normal js framework and it is using standard client (web)  server (backend apex) architecture. But maybe I am wrong and someone smarter would provide some more info about this topic

Comment: I agree with Charles. This seems like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You might want to take a step back and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @sfdcfox Lightning components are stored as a JSON object... perhaps it's possible to query for them. But of course, as Charles says, we are probably trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Of course, they would be in raw, unevaluated form... so many attributes would be invalid.

Answer (score 6):

No. Those parameters are known only on the front end and never passed to the back at all. The whole idea of making calls to static functions in an Apex controller from Lightning is that behaviour should flow directly from the parameters passed in.

This seems like an X/Y problem. The question you are asking is confusing. What is the real problem you are trying to solve that makes you so reluctant to pass Lightning component parameters to Apex?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in normal flow also because Lightning side, once spinned up on a page load, determines then when and how to call Apex code using Ajax calls or navigating to another page. Between calls, Apex has no chance to know what happening on Lightning side. This is how classic  client-server and unidirectional SPA applications work.

To implement something you talking about, you have to have a hypothetical constantly running background process on Apex, that will connect via always-live bidirectional  channel like  websocket to another hypothetical JavaScript daemon running on Lightning front-end session (btw each user in each browser will have a different session so different instance of a daemon), and this daemon will be somehow invisible to the Lightning components (your intention was to hide such an activity from the components itself - right?) and querying their attributes the same time.

Well, you can implement e.g a Chrome browser extension with a spying content script. This content script will hack into Lightning components structure in real time, and send its contents to some your server side when queried. But this is tricky, and again, server-initiated query needs technologies like websocket or long polling.

You can try to make the same hacks from a special lightning component or from a loaded static JS library instead of Chrome extension, but I suspect you might encounter security limitations from LockerService.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the use case of this (personally I can not think of any)? Possibly would help a bit more to find the correct solution to your problem. Seems like a case of over-engineering ;)